# Google Analytics is showing I have slow load time on certain URLs. When I load the URLs, they load extremely fast. Why?

Tags: google-analytics

Load times are displayed between 64 seconds and 388 seconds, but when I load the page, everything’s great. I don’t understand why? Anybody have experience with these types of insights that can provide me some insight?

For example, this URL:

https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/tools/content.cfm?ItemNumber=8631&SSO=1

... is showing a 388 second load on GA. It loads in 400ms in multiple browsers I've tested and throttled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give an exact answer since there are so many factors that could come into play. You can first start with running online website performance tools like:

[tools.pingdom.com](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/dqIsGU/https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/tools/content.cfm?ItemNumber=8631&SSO=1)

Or [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instituteforsupplymanagement.org%2Ftools%2Fcontent.cfm%3FItemNumber%3D8631%26SSO%3D1)

**Running both of these tools reveals that you can bundle and minify a lot of resources (javascript and css).** This will definitely help with the score and speed. By how much? You will have to implement the changes and test again.

Perhaps, when the page was being crawled and data collected, the server just happen to be running slow at that moment?

Comment: Great idea. Thanks for the assistance.